# ZEND_LONG_FMT error while installing xdebug on macos

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

When trying to install `xdebug` for `php 7.4` on my mac : `pecl install xdebug` I get this error during make:

```
cc -I. -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-dlrJPgTEe/xdebug-2.9.8/include -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-dlrJPgTEe/xdebug-2.9.8/main -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php/main -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src -I/private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-dlrJPgTEe/xdebug-2.9.8/src -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src/base/base.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o src/base/.libs/base.o/private/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/src/base/base.c:325:83: error: expected ')'
                zend_throw_exception_ex(zend_ce_error, 0, "Maximum function nesting level of '" ZEND_LONG_FMT "' reached, aborting!", XINI_BASE(max_nesting_level));
                                                                                                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.11/include/php/Zend/zend_long.h:57:28: note: expanded from macro 'ZEND_LONG_FMT'
# define ZEND_LONG_FMT "%" PRId64
```

My php & macos version are :

```
PHP 7.4.11 (cli) (built: Oct  1 2020 23:30:54) ( NTS )
System Version: macOS 10.15.7 (19H2)      
Kernel Version: Darwin 19.6.0
```

I did the same on another machine with same versions of php and macos but never had this error.

As far as I can understand the problem seems to come from the ZEND_LONG_FMT macro but i can't find out why this occurs on a specific machine.

I also followed the instructions given at [here](http://rob-santoro.com/how-to-php-mac-catalina-setup/) but the same error occurs.

I took a look at xdebug mantis and zend bug tracker but didn't find anything relevant.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you
David

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there is an Xdebug ticket for this too: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1876, but so far, I am puzzled on why this happens. The ZEND_LONG_FMT macro uses the PRId64 macro which your OS should define, through the `inttypes.h` header file.

In my case (on Linux) it is in `/usr/include/inttypes.h`, as:

```
#  define __PRI64_PREFIX    "ll"
...

# define PRId64     __PRI64_PREFIX "d"
```

I can see from a debugging file that my user has provided that it includes the file `/usr/local/include/inttypes.h`. As I don't have a mac, I can't check that file.

However, somebody else has stated that the `/usr/local/include/inttypes.h` file does not even exist on their OSX, and that instead that it should be
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/inttypes.h` instead.

Could `/usr/local/include/inttypes.h` have come from a weird source and messes things up?

In any case, I don't think this is a bug in either Xdebug (or PHP), but rather a broken header somewhere on OSX.

Comment: You're right !  removing the 'inttypes.h' from /usr/local/include solved the issue. Thanks a lot